# Using std::visit on a class inheriting from std::variant - libstdc++ vs libc++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, variant

Consider the following code snippet:

```
struct v : std::variant<int, std::vector<v>> { };

int main()
{
    std::visit([](auto){ }, v{0});
}
```

- clang++ 7 with `-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++2a` compiles the code;
- g++ 9 with `-std=c++2a` fails to compile the code, with the following error:

  > /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180711/include/c++/9.0.0/variant:94:29:
  >   error: incomplete type 'std::variant_size' used in nested name
  >   specifier
  >
  > ```
  >  inline constexpr size_t variant_size_v = variant_size<_Variant>::value;
  >
  >                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  > ```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/no8aRZ)

---

- **Are both implementations conforming to the Standard?**
- If not, what implementation is correct here, and why?

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but `-std=c++2a` isn't C++17, it's the yet-to-be finished C++20. Did you mean to ask about that?

Comment: Without inheritance, both compile: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/NZPdwf).

Comment: It is unrelated to "recursive variant", inheriting from simple `std::variant<int>` produces same issue [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/mnzcRL).

Comment: Both downvote and a close vote are totally unexplainable to me.

Comment: Obviously neither conforms to the non-existent [tag:C++2a] standard ;)

Comment: So all of the compilers used in the godbolt link in the question work now - but onlinegdb.com uses gcc 7 so it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Jarod42  I'm just curious how you would build a real visitor for your demo if you are going to call std::visit recursively.  I can't figure out how to make this work: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/chThrnPfY

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: Your structure doesn't have `variant` member. once done, your example should work with little change: [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s1nx15hjn).

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry.  I don't know what I was thinking.  I just took your demo and tried to use the visitor.  I should have paid more attention....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[[variant.visit] in C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/variant.visit) doesn't use `variant_size_v`, but it does in the [current working draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/variant.visit) as a result of an [editorial change](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/b4d7e7406dfa7c59591743dca9b79f30fa8f15bd). I don't see any indication that LWG reviewed the change before it went in, but it has looked at this part of the standard several times since then and has yet to object to it, so I'm going to postulate that it is in fact required.

Meanwhile, [LWG issue 3052](https://wg21.link/LWG3052), which has been referred to LEWG, would explicitly require `std::variant`. When that issue is resolved - one way or the other - it should resolve this too.

Comment: FWIW: Thomas and I decided this change was editorial under the interpretation that "all variants" has the obvious meaning of "specializations of `std::variant`." The fact that LWG referred 3052 to LEWG, indicates to me that we're not sure what the word "variants" means.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like it is a bug in gcc implementation. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), it is called as if calling `invoke` on a `std::get`. `std::get<>` is defined for anything which is convertible to `std::variant` (since it accepts a `std::variant` argument by forwarding reference). Your structure is convertible to `std::variant`, and so `std::get` itself works on your structure in gcc.

The fact that the gcc implementation chose to use a `std::variant_size` as part of its implementation of `visit` is their implementation detail, and the fact that it doesn't (and shouldn't) work for your struct is irrelevant.

Conclusion: It is a bug in gcc due to an oversight in implementation.

Comment: Citing cppreference for "is this legal" is questionable; in a question tagged [language-lawyer] it is just plain wrong.  cppreference contains "how to use" information that is reasonable; for implementation quirks it contains "lies we tell to children".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I agree, but I listed it for convenience. C++ 17 standard is no different in this regards, it has effectively the same wording.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue as well recently. I kind of came up with a workaround which basically specialises variant_size and variant_alternative for the class that inherits from the variant..

[link on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/AvjW69)

Its not pretty and it injects stuff into the std namespace. I'm not a metaprogramming expert (yet!) so its something I hacked together. Maybe someone else can improve on this?

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>



using var = std::variant<int, bool, float, std::string>;

struct myvar : public var {
    using var::var;
    using var::operator=;

};

namespace std{

    template<>
    struct variant_size<myvar> : variant_size<var> {
    };

    template<std::size_t I>
    struct variant_alternative<I,myvar> :  variant_alternative<I,var> {
    };
}

int main(){

    constexpr int vs = std::variant_size<var>::value;

    myvar s = std::string{"boo!"}; 
    std::visit([](auto&& e){std::cout << e << "\n";}, s);
    std::cout << vs;
}
```